# Looping function columns names R

Tags: r

My Data has the following form:

```
 Individual Year    X2011Int    X2010Int    X2009Int   X2008Int   X2007Int
      1     2011    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
      2     2010    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
      3     2009    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
      4     2008    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
```

Where the X2009Int, X2008Int, X2007Int columns represent the severity of a particular event at those specified time periods. My aim is to create a function which I can loop across columns to create the following:

```
 Individual   Year            T        T-1           T-2
  1             2011     =X2011Int   =X2010Int    =X2009Int
  2             2010     =X2010Int   =X2009Int    =X2008Int
  3             2009     =X2009Int   =X2008Int    =X2007Int
  4             2008     =X2008Int   =X2007Int    =X2006Int
```

To further illustrate what's going on take Individual 3 in Year 2009. Under the $T column I would need the event intensity value in X2009Int , $T-1 column = value from X2008Int, $T-2 = X2007Int, $T-3 = X2006Int, etc. (Years range from 2012-1980)

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Follow up:

I'm still having issues with my for-loop. The first iteration works perfectly, but does not seem to work after this.

The links to the data/code are:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B32x3hkj1P-IMWF6LVBoeE5tVFE

Any tips/ideas are very very much appreciated! :)

Comment: If we look at the first row Individual 1 in Year 2011. 
The first 0 would be the value of the $X2011Int variable in my original dataframe. The second 0 (T-1) would correspond to the value $X2010Int variable in my original dataframe. 
Likewise, the $T-2 value corresponds to the $X2009 value.

Comment: Can you give me a link to TOY2 (Google Drive, GitHub, etc)? or `dput` it or something?

Comment: Thanks. OK I am about to update my answer now.

Comment: It's updated, please have a look. If this was helpful please consider upvoting so that I can have another 5 points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the helpful update. I think this is what you want:

```
Individual Year    X2009Int    X2010Int    X2011Int
1     2011    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338
2     2011    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338
3     2010    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338
4     2010    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338
5     2009    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338
6     2009    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338

d <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header = T)

d1 <- data.frame(
  Individual = d$Individual,
  Year       = d$Year,
  T          = 0,
  "T-1"      = 0,
  "T-2"      = 0
)


# First let's rename the columns of the original data set to make it easier to use
nms <- colnames(d[,3:ncol(d)])
nms <- gsub("X", "", nms)
nms <- gsub("Int", "", nms)
nms <- c(colnames(d)[1:2],nms)

colnames(d) <- nms

# Now, let's populate the new data.frame
for(i in unique(d1$Year)){
  d1$T[d1$Year == i]    <- d[d$Year == i,colnames(d) == i]  
  d1$T1[d1$Year == i-1] <- d[d$Year == i-1,colnames(d) == i-1]  
  d1$T2[d1$Year == i-2] <- d[d$Year == i-2,colnames(d) == i-2]  

}
```

> ```
> Individual Year          T       T-1       T-2
> 1          1 2011 4789.33800        0        0
> 2          2 2011 4789.33800        0        0
> 3          3 2010   18.07049 18.07049        0
> 4          4 2010   18.07049 18.07049        0
> 5          5 2009   10.36703 10.36703 10.36703
> 6          6 2009   10.36703 10.36703 10.36703
> ```

**FOLLOW UP**

OK, so there are a couple of issues going on in the follow up code.

1. The class did not really get changed. Please comment out the `transform` statements and use this:

   `d1$Year   <- as.numeric(d1$Year)`

   `TOY2$Year <- as.numeric(TOY2$Year)`
2. I *think* you used `IntensityTOY` where you meant to use `TOY2`. I don't have `IntensityTOY` and I'm not familiar with your specific data, so I'm not sure, but please check if you want to change

   `nms <- colnames(TOY2[,3:ncol(IntensityTOY)])`

to

```
`nms <- colnames(TOY2[,3:ncol(TOY2)])`
```

3. You have some values of year that say `#N/A`. That can't be converted to numeric and will cause problems. Here's a solution:

   `d1$Year   <- gsub("#N/A","", d1$Year)` # Do this before as.numeric()

   `TOY2$Year <- gsub("#N/A","", TOY2$Year)`

One last thing. The `NA`s in your data may be problematic for subscripted assignments. There are several ways to fix this. If this error message comes up you may choose to change `NA` to 0, omit the NA's, impute them, or exclude them (`!is.na(...)`).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. 

If we could look to the edited section of my question I have a clearer example of my goal data.


Your code allows me to match the `Year` to the `T` column. How would I paste the values under the `T-1` and `T-2` columns? 
I imagine I would have to do this row-by-row for each unique Year and then loop across Years. 
Thanks!

Comment: @Recon93 I think I understand now. I have completely re-written my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @Recon93 By the way, I only did it through "T-2" but you could use the same process to do "T-3" or up to any number, even "T-40",etc.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to clearly set it out! You're the best !!!

Comment: Just a follow-up:
When I run the for-loop I receive the following error:
`Error in i - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`
I've tried to transform the `$Year` columns using `as.numeric` but it doesn't seem to change it.

Comment: @Recon93 If you can give me code to reproduce that error then I can fix it for you. I didn't get that error. Make sure you check the `class` of `Year` in both dataframes.

Comment: Yep sure thing, am editing the main question to include my follow up code.

Comment: Thanks for your updates. Just a question: 
When running the first point in your update `d1$Year <- as.numeric(d1$Year) TOY2$Year <- as.numeric(TOY2$Year)` I change all the values to numeric. 
But when I remove all the NA values using `TOY2$Year <- gsub("#N/A","", TOY2$Year)` the NAs are gone, but it's changed back to `character`. `transform` doesn't work :(

Comment: @Recon93  This is probably my fault because of how I explained it out of order. You need to do `gsub` before `as.numeric`. I actually never use `transform` so I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Recon93 `d1$Year   <- gsub("#N/A","", d1$Year);
TOY2$Year <- gsub("#N/A","", TOY2$Year);
d1$Year   <- as.numeric(d1$Year);
TOY2$Year <- as.numeric(TOY2$Year);
class(d1$Year)`

Comment: Yep just saw your updated update, will exclude the NAs from my dataset before transforming to numeric. THANKYOU for your help! (can i upvote you more even though my rep is only 8?)

Comment: I've bookmarked your blog in any case! Have a wonderful day/night!

Comment: @Recon93 You too! Cheers

Comment: I'm still running into issues :( The for-loop works well in the first iteration, but does not do as expected after. My code/data are linked in the question. I've done my head in trying to understand my mistake